# Python mock specs with properties from __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

When testing in Python using `mock.patch`, you can use spec to make sure your tests fail if properties not in your class are called.  But these don't let you use properties created in `__init__`:

```
class A(object):        
  def __init__(self):                                                                                  
    self.init_prop = 4

  def regular_prop():
    pass

with patch('__main__.A', spec=True) as A_mock:
   # accessing regular_prop on an instance of A_mock succeeds
   # accessing init_prop on an instance of A_mock raises an exception
```

Is there a way to make `patch` or another tool automatically catch attributes created in `__init__`?

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool. It doesn't work because the thing in the `__init__` is an instance attribute, not a property. The `patch` context manager/decorator is for class level attributes only.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on an appropriate tool?

Comment: I'm not aware of one. But that doesn't mean much. Hopefully somebody more knowledgeable can suggest one.

Comment: `A.init_prop` *shouldn't* work, because the original `A` doesn't have an `init_prop` attribute either. *Instances* of `A` have that attribute.

Comment: Good point, modified to show that it would be after you call the a_mock's __init__

Answer (score 0):

Since instance attributes are created only after an instance is actually instantiated, you would have to create an actual instance of the class in order to create a mock object spec'd with it. And if the instantiation involves any external resources, patch those as well in order to keep the unit test free of dependencies:

```
import sqlite3
from unittest.mock import patch

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_prop = sqlite3.connect('foo.db') # an external resource

with patch('sqlite3.connect'):
    a = A()

with patch('__main__.a', spec=True) as a_mock:
    print(a_mock.init_prop) # succeeds
```